# Wget Directory, Where? How?

Tags: linux, terminal, directory, wget, gnu

I'm new to Wget and do not know a great deal about it, I am learning more and more all the time and using trial and error. I have installed the $Wget function as described in the file download from GNU.

I have used the $wget function in terminal (I'm using mac), and I get the following message as shown below, initially I just wanted to see if it works, so I used an amazon URL for a book I am looking to buy. Can someone please let me know if this means my $wget is working? As I cannot see anywhere in the config files, or in the file that is running $wget that there has been anything downloaded from Amazon...

I do not know if I am being completely naive, however like I said I am new to $Wget so if someone could advise me on the above and let me know where I can learn more about it, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
  $wget http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1440323968/ref=as_li_ss_tl?          ie=UTF 
       8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1440323968&linkCode=as2&tag=1stwebdesigne-20
[1] 64445
[2] 64446
-bash: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1440323968/ref=as_li_ss_tl?    ie=UTF8:
No such file or directory
[3] 64447
[4] 64448
[5] 64449
[1]   Exit 127                $wget       http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1440323968/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8
[2]   Done                    camp=1789
[3]   Done                    creative=390957
[4]   Done                    creativeASIN=1440323968
[5]+  Done                    linkCode=as2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the URL in single quotes and add a target filename - like so:

```
wget 'http://example.com?q=one&hat=six' -O target.filename
```